# How do I get GIT to stop track a folder that I recently added to gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder with a bunch of files that I do not want to track. I don't want to remove them, I just want to keep them out of version control. This folder was recently added to gitignore, but when any of the files change they still show up as changed in GIT. I just want GIT to completly ignore this folder.

How do I do this? I searched around and found several similar questions but non that gave the answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git rm -rf --cached <folder>
```

`rm` -- remove files from version control

`-r` -- do it recursive

`-f` -- force non-empty directory removing

`--cached` -- actually do not remove files, just remove it from version control

[man git rm](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html)

If you also want to remove files from all revisions they was encoutered, you might use more powerful tool: [git filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html).

Comment: I can't get this to work. If my folder is named 'files' and I'm just outside of that folder, do I type: 

`git rm -rf --cached files` ?

It just says "fatal:pathspec 'yourpath/files' did not match any files.

Comment: Make sure your files really under version control:
`git ls-files`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
git rm --cached
```

Comment: I need to specify a file when I type this. It just gives me a bunch of parameters that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do what I wanted now. I did:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged files/
```

And got this respons:
    Ignoring path files/

When I do a git status now I don't get the list of removed/changed files that I did before. Seems like this is it for me.